# Can I fix a SDD drive that does not identify itself anymore?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have a failing SDD (Kingston SSDNOW KC300; 480GB), and when inserting it in my Fedora laptop, I get the following `dmesg`:

```
[18336.225549] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[18336.225785] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[18337.262289] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SandForc e{200026BB}      306A PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[18337.262664] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[18337.262893] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 64 512-byte logical blocks: (32.8 kB/32.0 KiB)
[18337.263183] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[18337.263185] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[18337.263476] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[18337.263478] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[18337.264839] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

It shows no partitions, and only 32.8kB of storage available. When opening `cfdisk`, it asks for a label. When choosing `gpt` or `dos`, it shows only one partition of 32kB.

Is there anything I can do to somehow revive this disk, or is it broken beyond repair?

Comment: Usually no. And if you're able to revive it, get data recovered ASAP then bin it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear the SSD has failed.  SSDs are entirely unlike hard drives. An SSD failure is normally terminal.

Most of us have learned to keep backups of varying degrees.

Best option:  Replace with a good quality SSD and restore what you can from backups.

SSD recovery can be quite expensive.

Comment: I have backups, that isn't the issue. It is just that this is the OS disk and reinstalling Windows and all programs is such a lot of work always ;-).

Comment: @BartFriederichs  Programs like Acronis True Image or Clonezilla can make a full backup and there re-installing programs/OS is not needed as long as you have a current backup.  Starting over is a lot of work, so I avoid it at all costs.